# PostMapping in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have already made a authentication process (using both: inMemoryAuthentication and jdbcAuthentication). It works fine for all users, which I insert to database manually.
In next step I'm trying to make a simple registration process, but my controller's PostMapping method didn't allow me to get user login and password.
The problem occurs only if didn't log in as for another account.
When I'm using /createUser mehod as logged user, it's work fine

That's my Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
@RequestMapping("/register")
    public String createNewUser() {
        System.out.println("register method");
        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/createUser")
    public String afterUserCreation(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("start method");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String confirmedPassword = request.getParameter("confirm_password");
        System.out.println("user: "+username + " pass: "+password+ " confirm: "+confirmedPassword);
        return "login";
    }
}


It's my Spring Security configuration

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("User").password("USER").roles("USER")
        .and().withUser("Admin").password("ADMIN").roles("ADMIN");

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, TRUE as enabled from auth_user_data where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from auth_user_data where username=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/addNew").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/*").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        .anyRequest().authenticated() 
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
        ;
    }
}

My HTML page:

<h1>Registr user:</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/createUser}" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username</label>: <input type="text"
                id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" /> <br />
            <label for="password">Password</label>: <input type="password"
                id="password" name="password" /> <br />
            <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>: <input type="password"
                id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"/> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create account" />
        </form>
```

I'm expecting to get username and password in my method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    .antMatchers("/login","/register").permitAll()
```

to

```
   .antMatchers("/login","/register","/createUser").permitAll()
```

**permitAll** tells Spring Security that no authentication is required to access this URL. That URL is */createUser* in your case.